# Нужна ли здесь запятая перед "или"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая?

*В купон на педикюр входит обработка стопы аппаратом, или по желанию клиента жидкостью с доплатой.*

Comment: "Обработка" не может "входить в купон": купон - это _документ_, которым предусмотрены соотв. процедуры (в их число и "входит" обработка).

Answer (score 0):

Обработка аппаратом или жидкостью, — никаких знаков: однородные члены.

[В предложении с однородными членами перед  одиночным союзом ***или*** запятая не ставится.](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/kogda-pered-soyuzom-ili-stavitsya-zapyataya.html)

Comment: а если имеется ввиду что: "аппаратам" или "аппаратам с жидкостью"

Comment: Лена, то же самое: аппаратом простым или аппаратом особенным (с жидкостью). ***Иметь в виду*** пишется в три слова.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Мне кажется, что запятая в Вашем ответе (предложении) не нужна.

Comment: Римуля, сочтём ея авторской. )))